# For some obscure reason my image is not getting displayed in my react app but does work anywhere else

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to display a picture as my background for the page and I am using styled components

This is the code

```
const BG = styled.div`
background-image: url("p3.gif");
height: 100%; 
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
`

function PageOne() {
    return (
        <>
                <BG></BG>
        </>
    )
}
```

I have seen the exactly same result here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_full_page

But for some reason it doesn´t seem to work in this react app ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure your html and body tags have `height: 100%` style applied? And every other component in the DOM tree above `BG` component?

Comment: Thank you I deleted my #root and so it wasn´t applied there but I added it and now it works !